# Presto sql to get last months data till current day data?

Tags: sql, date, presto

How to get last month's data using presto sql

tried this :

```
SELECT *
FROM tabl
where my_date > cast(current_date - interval '1' month as timestamp)
```

But this will include current months and exclude some previous months days

How to get only last months data and current month data  included like this

`last month  data + data until today`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `date_trunc()`:

```
where my_date < date_trunc('month', current_date) and
      my_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' month
```

If you want everything since the first day of the previous month:

```
where my_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' month
```